# How can I keep the existing guides when the underlying file is updated in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

I sometimes update the underlying file outside Photoshop:

[image]

Existing guides in Photoshop are then lost by default. How can I keep the existing guides when the underlying file is updated in Photoshop?

Comment: Are you using a Smart Object (a linked file)?  If you add the guides in the main document PSD (not inside the Smart Object), they should remain when the jpeg is updated. Obviously you need to save the PSD, since this will contain the guides. The jpeg format doesn't support guides.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks, i wasn't but that sounds like a good solution!

Comment: I've added that as an answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Use file format that supports guides. Basically with jpeg, png etc it does not work since they have no way of storing the guide data. Alternatively use a smart object inside your psd file that is a linked file

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it using a Smart Object

1. Do *File > Open as Smart Object*, navigate to the jpeg image you want to use, select and open it.
2. Add your guides.
3. Save as PSD.

Now if you update the jpeg outside of Photoshop, the guides will still remain in the PSD. You will have to open the PSD to see them.

Note: If the smart object doesn't update automatically after you made a change outside Photoshop, then right click the Smart Object in the layers panel and choose "Update Modified Content".